# Actionscript: Output of for..in loop changes between Flash IDE and display in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am using GraphicElements and TextElements to build menus in AS3 that display a combination of text and graphics. The menus appear as expected (example 1) when published from the Flash IDE, but their content appears in a completely different order when displayed in the Flash player in a browser (FF and IE at this stage). The IDE is publishing to Flash player 25, but the mis-ordering of content happens in Flash player versions from 11.x up to 27.x

Here is the code:

```
private function buildMenu(obj:Object,rev:Boolean):Object {
//trace ('here is the title: '+obj.title);          
var groupVector:Vector.<ContentElement> = new Vector.<ContentElement>(); 

for (var i in obj)
{
    if (obj[i] != null)
    {
        //trace ('as a string: '+String(i));
        switch(String(i))
        {
            case "icon" :
                //trace ('you found an icon: '+obj[i]); 
                var graphicElement:GraphicElement = new GraphicElement(obj[i],obj[i].width,obj[i].height/2,obj.tCol);
                groupVector.unshift(graphicElement);
                break;
            case "title" :
                //trace ('you found a title');
                var textElement:TextElement = new TextElement(obj.title, obj.tCol); 
                groupVector.push(textElement);
                break;
            case "data" :
                //trace ('you found data');
                for (var y in obj[i])
                {
                    var tmpitem = obj[i][y];
                    //trace ('typeof y: '+typeof(tmpitem));
                    if (tmpitem!= null)
                    {
                        if (typeof(tmpitem) == "object")
                        {
                            //trace ('y is a graphic: '+tmpitem+'......'+tmpitem.width);
                            var graphicElement:GraphicElement = new GraphicElement(tmpitem,tmpitem.width,tmpitem.height/2,obj.tCol);
                            groupVector.push(graphicElement);   
                        } else 
                        {
                            //trace ('y is text: '+tmpitem);
                            var textElement:TextElement = new TextElement(tmpitem, obj.dataCol); 
                            groupVector.push(textElement);
                        }                                           
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;          
        }
    }
}
if (rev) //turns the entry around to list from the right
{
    groupVector.reverse();
}

//working lines
var groupElement = new GroupElement(groupVector); 
var textBlock:TextBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.content = groupElement; 
var textLine:TextLine = textBlock.createTextLine(null, 400);
return textLine;
}
```

[Here is the expected output (published within the Flash IDE):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lNGE.png)

[And here is the same published swf displayed in a browser:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgABV.png)

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it please?

Comment: That is expected behavior. Sadly, objects are enumerated like that, there's no way to predict the order of **for..in** enumeration or rely on it. You need to sort the result or test these properties in a desired order without **for..in** loop.

Comment: You can structure your graphic object before (as a render) so put the value (from your array) in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of your outer `for in` loop.

```
if (obj.icon)
{
            //trace ('you found an icon: '+obj[i]); 
            var graphicElement:GraphicElement = new GraphicElement(obj[i],obj[i].width,obj[i].height/2,obj.tCol);
            groupVector.unshift(graphicElement);
}

if (obj.title)
{
            //trace ('you found a title');
            var textElement:TextElement = new TextElement(obj.title, obj.tCol); 
            groupVector.push(textElement);
}

if (obj.data)
{
            //trace ('you found data');
            for (var y in obj.data)
            {
                var tmpitem = obj.data[y];
                //trace ('typeof y: '+typeof(tmpitem));
                if (tmpitem!= null)
                {
                    if (typeof(tmpitem) == "object")
                    {
                        //trace ('y is a graphic: '+tmpitem+'......'+tmpitem.width);
                        var graphicElement:GraphicElement = new GraphicElement(tmpitem,tmpitem.width,tmpitem.height/2,obj.tCol);
                        groupVector.push(graphicElement);   
                    } else 
                    {
                        //trace ('y is text: '+tmpitem);
                        var textElement:TextElement = new TextElement(tmpitem, obj.dataCol); 
                        groupVector.push(textElement);
                    }                                           
                }
            }
}
```

As for your inner `for in` loop, we'll need to know more about what `obj.data` is. Is it an `object`? How many properties could it have? If its properties need to be read in a specific order then it should be an `Array` instead of an `object`. If not, you can still simplify your code by using `for each in` instead of `for in`.

```
            for each (var tmpitem in obj.data)
            {
                // No need for var tmpitem = obj.data[y];
```

Comment: Good approach Kyle, thanks. I ended up changing the code to use an Array, because the specific order is important in this instance.